# how to call different method for different product-flavor from common java class

Tags: android, android-productflavors, android-build-flavors

I need something like this:

from any method:

```
if(for one flavor)

   do something

else

   do something
```

How can I handle flavors from java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify files for flavors. If I were you I would do something like this:
put a file in the `main/java/your/package` source, lets call it `CustomClass.java`.
It contains something like this:

```
public class CustomClass {
   public static void myCustomMethod() {
      //Do something here...
   }
}
```

After that you can create a flavor specific version of this class in the flavor name folder (next to the main folder).
So put a CustomClass.java in here: `your_flavor_name/java/your/package`
And do something else:

```
  public class CustomClass {
       public static void myCustomMethod() {
          //Do something here for that specific flavor!
       }
    }
```

The build will merge the files and use the specific ones for you flavor, and use the main version if no flavor specific file found. You can use it for drawables, and every other file (assets, ...).

You only have to create a new flavor after this. In your gradle add this:

```
productFlavors {
        your_flavor_name {
            applicationId "your.package"
        }
}
```

More stuff here: http://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your answer @GaborNovak

In fact, I searched something like that for common class:

```
if("flavor-name".equals(getApplicationContext().getPackageName())){
                myIntent.setClass(thisClass.this, nextClass.class);
            }
            else {
                myIntent.setClass(thisClass.this, nextClass.class);
            }
```

I think it is a bit confusing. When I write getApplicationContext.getpackageName  -> it gets defined application_id of selected flavor in build gradle.
When I write BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID  ->  it gets package name. Is there anybody who can explain behind of that logic? Isn't it confusing?

Answer (score 0):

define two `string.xml` for the two `product-flavors` separately and add a string of common name in each, for example,add `<string name="flavor">Flavor One</string>`in the `string.xml` of 1st flavor and add `<string name="flavor">Flavor Two</string>`in the `string.xml` of 2nd flavor. Now in the method, get the value of string `flavor` and add lines of code accordingly. 
Because, for the two flavors, the string flavor will have two different values.

Answer (score 0):

Create class in something() in productFlavor :

Main Common source :

```
main\java\com.exmaple.test\class.java - > something()
```

Flavor1 source :

```
flavor\java\com.exmaple.test\class.java - > something()
```

Flavor2 source :

```
flavor\java\com.exmaple.test\class.java - > something()
```